# seg fault/undefined behavior in comparator function of std::map

Tags: c++, c++11, segmentation-fault, undefined-behavior

this has been confusing me today.

I'm having trouble understanding why the code below seg faults on the final insertion into the test_map.  Using emplace(), insert() both work as expected, but using the [] operator fails.  I've read the relevant C++ documentation for [] but the behavior observed below doesn't seem to match up with what i've read.

I've stepped through in GDB and noted that it was failing when trying to compare strings inside the comparator function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

class Testkey {
public:
    std::string s1;
    int64_t id;
    Testkey(const char* s1_, int64_t id_): s1(s1_), id(id_) {}

    bool operator<(const Testkey& rhs) const {
        if (s1 < rhs.s1)
            return true;
        if (id < rhs.id)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
};

int main() {
    Testkey i1("69739", 748072524);
    Testkey i2("69728", 52608624);
    Testkey i3("69725", 750212380);
    Testkey i4("68988", 55027788);

    std::map<Testkey, int> test_map;
    test_map[i1] = 1;
    test_map[i2] = 2;
    test_map[i3] = 3;
    std::cout << "hmm.." << std::endl;
    test_map[i4] = 4; // seg faults here in comparator function...
    std::cout << "done" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I've attached a repl here
https://repl.it/repls/RundownSparklingComment

Comment: With your logic, both "(1, 2) < (2, 1)" and "(2, 1) < (1, 2)" are true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your comparison function is broken. You probably meant this:

```
bool operator<(const Testkey& rhs) const {
    if (s1 < rhs.s1)
        return true;
    if (s1 > rhs.s1)
        return false;
    if (id < rhs.id)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

The comparison function use for `std::map` must define a [strict weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering) of the objects to be inserted or compared and your function doesn't since both `i3<i2` and `i2<i3` are true.

Comment: forgive me if im misunderstanding, but would a broken comparison function cause a seg fault/UB? wouldn't it just end up inserting my record into the map into the wrong place, at worst?

Comment: It depends how broken the comparison function is. If it's so broken, it can't identify any place at all, then anything can happen. Trying to put `i3` before `i2` and `i2` before `i3` at the same time doesn't provide any particular wrong place to put things. (In my STL, the insertion checks to make sure it won't run off the end, runs the code that doesn't handle the run off the end case, but then runs off the end anyway and accesses out of bounds.)

Comment: @shinjin -- FYI, for the Visual C++ compiler, a broken comparison operator would lead to an `assert` failure in the debug runtime.  So no, the worse is not merely putting the record in the wrong place.